# What is the difference between key exchange algorithm and the authentication algorithm in SSL?

Tags: tls

I have two questions about SSL protocol:

- What is the difference between key exchange algorithm and the
  authentication algorithm?
- At any step of SSL handshake the authentication algorithm will
  be used?